# Query with where in (SubQuery) not working

Tags: mysql

My query not working when using subquery

I have shop product table

```
"auto_id"   "category"  "name"  "last_update"
"1"     "1"     "BOOK"  "2018-12-06 17:35:19"
"2"     "1"     "BOOK"  "2018-09-26 10:45:08"
"7"     "1"     "PENCIL"    "2018-10-09 08:50:40"
"8"     "1"     "BOOK"  "2018-12-04 14:39:32"
"9"     "4"     "RULER" "2018-10-11 06:45:50"
"10"        "2"     "PAPER" "2018-11-13 08:35:34"
"11"        "1"     "Pen"   "2018-11-28 11:54:18"
"12"        "2"     "ERASER"    "2018-11-28   12:06:36"
"13"        "2"     "PAPER F4"  "2018-12-10 16:43:08"
"14"        "2"     "PAPER F4"  "2018-12-05 05:53:30"
"15"        "1"     "BOOK"  "2018-12-10 16:42:37"

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT('"',z.name,'"')))  AS n
FROM shop_product z 
WHERE z.category = 2 AND DATE(z.last_update) BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

And result

```
"PAPER F4","PAPER","ERASER"
```

And where running full query using not have result

```
SELECT a.id FROM shop_product AS a WHERE a.name IN (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT('"',z.name,'"')))  AS n
FROM shop_product z 
WHERE z.category = 2 AND DATE(z.last_update) BETWEEN '2018-07-01'AND '2018-12-31')
```

It shows the result if I change subquery using result string before

```
SELECT a.id FROM shop_product AS a WHERE a.name IN ("PAPER F4","PAPER","ERASER")
```

How to I get data using subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that concat() and group_concat() functions junk. Just use a simple subselect.

```
SELECT a.`auto_id`, a.`category`, a.`name`, a.`last_update`
FROM shop_product a 
WHERE name IN(
    SELECT z.`name`
    FROM shop_product z
    WHERE z.category = 2 
    AND DATE(z.last_update) 
    BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-12-31'
)
```